# SQL Server profiler trace template, copy over to newer version

Tags: sql-server, templates, profiler, trace

The "export the template from older SQL Server Profiler then import it to the newer SQL Server Profiler" approach as described in "[Can profiler templates be migrated to newer versions of SQL Profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538494/)" never worked for me.

The import is always successful, however when I "New" to start a new trace, the "*imported*" trace template is not in the drop down list.

The doc at
https://bradmcgehee.com/2009/12/06/getting-the-most-out-of-sql-server-profiler-using-templates/
says,

> [you can] export the trace definition for the template to a **Transact-SQL file**, which you can then use to create a SQL Trace definition.
>
> This code can be run as it is, or modified as needed, to create a trace definition for use with SQL Trace. It is much faster to create your SQL Trace definitions this way...

This is the routine that I prefer to migrate my SQL Server Profiler templates, but I don't know how to make SQL Server Profiler to use the exported Transact-SQL file.